# Python BaseHTTPServer calls Finish() before I'm done writing to the wfile output stream

Tags: python, rest, sockets, http, go

I'm trying to serve large files in response to an HTTP GET request with a Python web server. I've overridden do_GET(self) successfully and everything works great for sending small zip files but with larger files I only write around 137MB into the wfile output stream before I get a broken pipe error as BaseHTTPServer is calling finish before I'm done writing.

```
self.send_header("Content-Type", "application/octet-stream")
self.end_headers()
f = open(filename, 'rb')
fullyWritten = False
count = 0
while not fullyWritten:
        tmp = f.read(32768)
        count = count + len(tmp) 
        print count # always a different number before crash
        if not tmp:
            fullyWritten = True
        else:
            self.wfile.write(tmp) # never finishes writing large files
            print "wrote to http body"
```

`...
...
wrote to http body
137134080
wrote to http body
137166848
wrote to http body
137199616
----------------------------------------`

`Exception happened during processing of request from ('127.0.0.1', 43644)
        Traceback (most recent call last):
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 295, in _handle_request_noblock
            self.process_request(request, client_address)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 321, in process_request
            self.finish_request(request, client_address)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 334, in finish_request
            self.RequestHandlerClass(request, client_address, self)
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 651, in __init__
            self.finish()
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/SocketServer.py", line 710, in finish
            self.wfile.close()
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 279, in close
            self.flush()
          File "/usr/lib/python2.7/socket.py", line 303, in flush
            self._sock.sendall(view[write_offset:write_offset+buffer_size])
        error: [Errno 32] Broken pipe
----------------------------------------`

GO code that's calling the end point:

`res, err := http.Get(remoteUri)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    defer res.Body.Close()
    bodyBytesBuffer := new(bytes.Buffer)
    _, err = io.Copy(bodyBytesBuffer, res.Body)
    if err != nil {
        return err
    }
    urlReader := bytes.NewReader(bodyBytesBuffer.Bytes())
    var zipReader *zip.Reader
    zipReader, err = zip.NewReader(urlReader, int64(urlReader.Len()))`

Comment: You usually get a broken pipe only if the peer (i.e. client in this case) closes the connection but you still continue to write. Thus I recommend to check that case, maybe by doing a packet capture and looking who sends the first FIN (connection close). I would expect the client to do it.

Comment: It’s normal for `finish` to be called. It happens for every request. The problem is that the connection is closed while `finish` is still sending the data.

Comment: What client do you use to download the file?

Comment: I'm using go to call the python end point. I can definitely add that code. EDIT: GO code added.

Comment: So you're downloading the whole file to memory in your go client? Are you sure it's not running out of memory? What happens if you use a different client to download that url to a file?

Comment: @mata the file size received on the go-side is different every time after the bytes are written to disk. The file that we're trying to send is less than 300MB on a modern computer so memory shouldn't be an issue from what I can tell.

Comment: So if you use `wget` or `curl` also only part of the file is downloaded? You also should consider sending a `Content-Length` header to tell the client how much data it should expect.

Comment: @mata great idea with curl. will give that a shot and also check out the Content-Length header.